# BA Flight Number In October 1974

Tags: air-travel, british-airways

I am hoping to get the flight number of a BA flight from LHR to Sydney Airport (Kingsford smith) leaving LHR on Monday 14th October 1974 and arriving in Sydney on Wednesday 16th October 1974 Travelling via Frankfurt, Tehran, Bombay, Hong Kong and Darwin.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Do any of the data sources mentioned there go back that far?  I'd be surprised if they do.

Comment: I'm really curious why the flight number is desired!

Comment: http://www.departedflights.com is a repository of old airline timetables, but unfortunately they don't have anything covering what you want.  The closest is a BA timetable from 1980.

Comment: @NateEldredge I read through the answer and it mentioned at least one data source going back to 1970.

Comment: The World Bank data set is only claimed to show *number* of flights, not flight numbers, and moreover it's 404.

Comment: Checked in with the BA museum, suspect it was BA888 but can't confirm until lockdown ends and can retrieve the timetable from collection.